# In Actionscript 3, how are frame scripts compiled?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Or maybe I should ask "how the MainTimeline class is composed"?

How exactly are the codes in frame scripts organized into a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [article](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/943/2/Actionscript-and-timelines/Page2.html) which can help you understand all the nature of timelines.

Answer (score 0):

Although, one could potentially write a long answer how this is being done, your best bet would be to get one of the SWF decompilers out there (e.g. Sothink SWF Decompiler) and decompile a simple movie with frame scripts to see for yourself.

Comment: Maybe where can I find the specification? Actually I'm quite familiar with the the as3 bytecode, but now I find real behavior of actionscript is more or less undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

For a look at what happens under the hood, a decompiler will help you out a lot.  Just make a swf with some frame scripts and see what the decompiler shows you as the result.

I wrote a blog post about this very topic a while back.  Let me know if it is instructive.
http://www.scriptocalypse.com/?p=101